# ons.notification内で改行したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

[ons.notification](http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons.notification.html).alertのメッセージ内で改行したいのですが、うまく動作しません。
「`<br>`」「`\n`」「`\\n`」の3つを試してみたのですが、そのまま文字として表示されてしまい、改行できませんでした。
どうすれば改行できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[アラートダイアログを使う](http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingAlert)

のサンプルにコメントで書いてありますが、messageではなくmessageHTMLを使用します。

```
ons.notification.alert({
    // message: 'メッセージ',
    messageHTML: 'メッセージが<br>改行されました。',
    // もしくはmessageHTML: '<div>HTML形式のメッセージ</div>',
    title: 'ダイアログのタイトル',
    buttonLabel: 'OK',
    animation: 'default', // もしくは'none'
    // modifier: 'optional-modifier'
    callback: function() {
        // ボタンがタップされた
    }
});
```

Comment: 見落としてました！ありがとうございました！正しく改行できました。